# How to improve a company's reporting structure?

Tags: reporting, ssrs-2008-r2

I know a company that has spent it's history on depending on excel spreadsheets

How do I:

-Create a structure to have the front end users complete forms that turn into excel results for me on the back end?

Comment: When you created your account here, you agreed to take the [tour] and review the [help] pages to become more familiar with the site. It's clear you haven't yet done so; please do that now before posting your next question here. This site is for **specific questions** about **actual problems**. This question is in no way specific. It's as broad as *How do I design the next (FaceBook|Instagram|Twitter|Other site du jour).

Comment: I thought my question was specific in identifying that my company uses excel for everything and wanting some help to combine all of the excel sheets in a way where a feed could occur to consolidate the many areas

Comment: It's not specific in any way.

Comment: OK. I will remove the question and post elsewhere. Thanks for advising